# Uitableviewcell hight row dynamically rows & sections

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, iso

I want to have dynamically rows height size 
Here is the code ,works great  for dynamically high for each row works great 
but I want to have section for 2 rows and the codes don't work

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

        return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 5);
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;



    cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {


        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];



        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

        [label setTag:1];



             label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }


    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:text];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN-5, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN+20, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - ((CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2)+6), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];
```

now i replaced this code

```
 NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

by this one

```
 NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:([indexPath section]*2 + [indexPath row])];
```

I get the frame size row 0 & 1 for all rows